# How to lie to program about `process.platform`?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

There is a CLI that runs on Node and can be executed via `command` on the command line. In its code, some functionality is deactivated for Windows users by `if (process.platform === 'win32') { process.exit(1); }`. Now I want to disable this check, and allow Windows users to use the "hidden" functionality (usually the the required software is not installed on Windows, but I have a special setup where it is).

Is there some way, to lie to this CLI and simulate that it is running on e.g. Linux or macOS?

Of course I could fork the CLI, remove the check and work with my own version - but this would require repeating this process for each release. As this functionality should also be available to other users, I would have to publish the forked and modified CLI which could be a frequent source of confusion for its users (What about version numbers? Do I use the same `command`?) - 99.9% of the code will stay untouched.

Could I maybe write my own CLI, that does something to "fake" the environment, then executes the installed, original CLI, and cleans up afterwards?

---

I created an example package that works identical to the CLI, but only does exactly that part that I am investigating:

- https://github.com/janpio/nodejs-cli-nowin
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-cli-nowin

Install via `npm i -g nodejs-cli-nowin`.

Comment: The case is specific to a package. Please, specify package name.

Comment: It is not really, but I created https://github.com/janpio/nodejs-cli-nowin https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-cli-nowin that recreated the behavior for testing. Install via `npm i -g nodejs-cli-nowin`.

Comment: It doesn't clarify the problem because it depends on package internals. I provided an answer in general. It's impossible to say whether it's applicable without seeing how the package works.

Comment: I understand after reading your answer. Package I am looking at right now is [`weex-toolkit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weex-toolkit): `npm i -g weex-toolkit`, `weex create weex`, `weex platform add ios`, `weex run ios` or `weex build ios` then execute the condition. Code with the `process.platform` is [here](https://github.com/weexteam/weex-pack/blob/d125e25e87c933bd725be584ab96bd059c2371f8/src/utils/index.js#L137-L154), but to be honest I don't understand yet how this is called in `weex-toolkit`. Plugin loading somehow :/

Comment: So is it weex-toolkit or weex-pack? They seem to be different packages. I checked it, it has a bunch of dependencies, you can be sure that wrong process.platform will mess up a lot of platform-dependent things. The best thing you could do is to mock `process` in specific module, i.e. modify [module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) to add *local* process variable, `var process = isModuleWherePlatformIsMocked ? Object.create(global.process, { platform: { value: 'linux' } }) : global.process`.

Comment: I seriously doubt that monkey-patching the package right that is a good thing. You will have to hard-code it to specific module location where `process` should be mocked, if original package changes somehow, a patch will be broken. At this point forking would be cleaner.

Comment: The CLI is `weex-toolkit`, but as far as I understood it the `weex run ios` command is actually running logic from `weex-pack` - but I couldn't find out where/why for now.

Comment: weex toolkit doesn't have weex-pack as a dependency. It seems to be a replacement for weex-pack. Both have `weex` CLI command. FWIW, this module https://github.com/weexteam/weex-pack/blob/d125e25e87c933bd725be584ab96bd059c2371f8/src/utils/index.js#L137-L154 already was modified in latest weex-pack. That's why trying to patch specific module where `process.platform` is used is not a good idea. When package internasl change, your tool breaks.

Comment: `weex-toolkit` somehow installs `weex-pack`, when I reply `n` to `weex platform add ios` when the iOS stuff is already added, I get `02:40:11 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Jan\.xtoolkit\node_modules\weexpack\lib\platform\index.js:214:55 ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, wrapper package should be used to provide entry point instead of original package. `process.platform` should be mocked with new value before original package runs.

*wrapper-package/index.js*

```
Object.defineProperty(process, 'platform', { value: 'linux' });

require('original-package/bin/entry-point.js');
```

This won't affect child processes if original package spawns them.

This doesn't guarantee that the package will work as intended with mocked platform, there's a good chance that it won't. Even if the package itself works correctly, this may result in unpredictable behaviour in package dependencies that rely on `process.platform`.

In order to affect `process.platform` only for specific module, `platform` global should be shadowed with local variable. To do this, module wrapper function should be modified:

```
const Module = require('module')

const escapedPatchedModulePath = require.resolve('original-package/module-to-patch.js')
  .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');

Module.wrapper[0] += `
const isPatchedModule = __filename === "${escapedPatchedModulePath}";
let process = isPatchedModule
  ? Object.create(global.process, { platform: { value: 'linux' } })
  : global.process;
`;

require('original-package/bin/entry-point.js');
```

Comment: Ironically spawning child processes doesn't work as node tries to use `bin/sh` for it: `child_process.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: spawnSync /bin/sh ENOENT` ;)

Comment: Makes sense. Mocked `process.platform` will break every thing in Node that has dynamic platform-dependent code.

Comment: But in general your code works! Maybe there is a way to only apply it before specific modules/methods/calls?

Comment: I posted an example how module wrapper can be modified to change process.platform in specific module. I cannot say if this can be easily applied to your case. Such patch is fragile, I'd suggest to avoid this if possible.

Comment: Holy moly, that really works! What a great and and terrible piece of code :D I was playing around with the possibility to define a getter in `Object.defineProperty`, but didn't get anywhere because I didn't know who was calling the method. You are awesome, thanks!